# Pendrive not recognized and unable to mount it

Tags: debian, command-line, mount, usb-drive

Yesterday I mounted a pendrive from the command line using the following commands:

```
mkdir /media/usb-drive
mount /dev/sdc1 /media/usb-drive/
```

Then I unmounted it with the umount command:

```
umount /media/usb-drive
```

Today I turned on my notebook(with `Parrot OS` a `Debian` distro), I entered the pendrive and the system does not seem to recognize it. No command line commands like `lsusb`, `dmesg`, `fdisk -l`, recognize it. How can I solve this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Did you try on another computer? Did you try some other USB drive on the notebook? If you say "No command line commands ... recognize it", do you mean there's *absolutely* no hint of the device in the output? And also try `udevadm monitor`. Add new discoveries to the question text.